# Overriding a method, mypy throws an "incompatible with super type" error when changing return type to child class type

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding, mypy, python-typing

For the following code:

```py
class Person:
    number: int

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.number = 0

    def __add__(self, other: 'Person') -> 'Person':
        self.number = self.number + other.number
        return self


class Dan(Person):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def __add__(self, other: 'Dan') -> 'Dan':
        self.number = self.number + other.number + 1
        return self
```

MyPy Output:

```
test.py:15: error: Argument 1 of "__add__" is incompatible with supertype "Person"; supertype defines the argument type as "Person"  [override]
test.py:15: note: This violates the Liskov substitution principle
test.py:15: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides
```

I would think that the child type, `Dan`, is more specific than `Person` and would not violate the Liskov substitution principle.

My first thought for a solution was to create a type variable `person_co = TypeVar("person_co", bound=Person)`. But that did not work because `Person` was not yet defined. I also tried making the argument and return type `Person` for the `__add__` method in `Dan`. That worked and MyPy did not throw errors but that is not correct, right?

Comment: "would not violate the Liskov substitution principle"—Well, on a `Person` you can call `add` and give it *any* `Person`. If you can't call `add` on a `Dan` and give it *any* `Person`, then it's not being substitutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why it violates the LSP

The LSP states that method return types are covariant, whereas method parameter types are **contravariant** in the subtype. You shall not strengthen the preconditions, i.e. you shall not require `Dan` -- a strict subtype of `Person` -- for `other` in the `Dan.__add__` method, if you annotated `other` with `Person` in the signature of `Person.__add__`.

Look at the following function:

```py
def f(p: Person, q: Person) -> None:
    out = p + q
    print(out.number)
```

Since `p` must be a `Person`, I expect that I can pass some `Dan` instance to it. I can also pass some `Person` instance to `q`. I would expect `p + q` to work because I expect I can **substitute** any `Dan` instance, where a `Person` instance is required.

Your definition of the overridden method `Dan.__add__` would mean that I can **not** pass a `Dan` instance for `p` because your method would not actually allow `q` to be any `Person`, only `Dan`.

That is why your code violates the Liskov substitution principle. It is not because of the return type annotation, but because of the argument type annotation.

---

### Option A: Just stick to `Person`

From your example it seems you have a few different options to fix this.

The simplest one would be to keep `other: Person` in your overridden method:

```py
from __future__ import annotations


class Person:
    number: int

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.number = 0

    def __add__(self, other: Person) -> Person:
        self.number = self.number + other.number
        return self


class Dan(Person):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def __add__(self, other: Person) -> Dan:
        self.number = self.number + other.number + 1
        return self
```

This seems reasonable since your method only relies on `other` having the `number` attribute and it being something that can be added to an integer.

(By the way, you can omit the quotation marks, if you add `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of your module.)

---

### Option B: Type variable for genericity

A more sophisticated option is the one you mentioned that uses a type variable, making the method generic in terms of one (or both) of its parameters. You can set the upper bound by enclosing it in quotes, if its definition comes later. (Here the `__future__` import doesn't help us.)

Something like this works:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar


P = TypeVar("P", bound="Person")


class Person:
    number: int

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.number = 0

    def __add__(self: P, other: Person) -> P:
        self.number = self.number + other.number
        return self


class Dan(Person):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def __add__(self: P, other: Person) -> P:
        self.number = self.number + other.number + 1
        return self
```

Now the return type will depend on what exact subtype of `Person` the called method is bound to. This means that even without an additional override an instance of any subclass `P` of `Person` calling `__add__` would return that same type `P`.

The `other` parameter could of course also be annotated with `P`, but that would result in `P` collapsing the the next common ancestor, if `self` and `other` are **different**, which in practice would mean that you could only add a **subtype** of `Dan` to an instance of `Dan`. That would be a much stronger requirement. I don't know, if you want that.

---

### Option C: Protocol for maximum flexibility

Lastly, to show a completely different approach, you could leverage structural subtyping (introduced by [PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/)) by declaring that the only relevant aspect about `other` is its `number` and that it can be added to an `int` (for example because it is also an `int`). You could define a `Protocol` that stands for any type that has such an attribute. This would be a much *broader* definition for your method:

```py
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar


P = TypeVar("P", bound="Person")


class HasNumber(Protocol):
    number: int


class Person:
    number: int

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.number = 0

    def __add__(self: P, other: HasNumber) -> P:
        self.number = self.number + other.number
        return self


class Dan(Person):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def __add__(self: P, other: HasNumber) -> P:
        self.number = self.number + other.number + 1
        return self
```

Note that this means that some completely unrelated class (in terms of nominal inheritance) that has the `number` attribute of the type `int` can be added to an instance of `Person`. From the way your example is written, I don't see any problem with that and it is arguably more in line with the dynamic philosophy of Python.

---

### Option D: [`Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self) for Python `3.11+`

Similarly to what SUTerliakov wrote in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75214461/19770795), you could simply indicate that `__add__` returns whatever type the class is.

Combining this with the `Protocol` from Option C would seem to be a nice combination of simplicity (no need for a type variable and no need to annotate lowercase `self`) and flexibility (*"if it quacks like a duck..."*):

```py
from typing import Protocol, Self


class HasNumber(Protocol):
    number: int


class Person:
    number: int

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.number = 0

    def __add__(self, other: HasNumber) -> Self:
        self.number = self.number + other.number
        return self


class Dan(Person):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def __add__(self, other: HasNumber) -> Self:
        self.number = self.number + other.number + 1
        return self
```

Mix and match as you wish. As you can see, there are many options.

Comment: What if I had another function, `some_function()`, defined in Dan that is not in Person, that wanted to use in the `__add__` function. Eg. `other.some_function()`. MyPy says `some_function()` does not exist. And changing the type do `Dan` so mypy see's that function breaks the LSP.

Comment: @ShaneHeldsinger In that case you _would_ actually need two distinct type variables. `P = TypeVar("P", bound="Person")` for `Person.__add__` and `D = TypeVar("D", bound="Dan")` for `Dan.__add__` and you _would_ have to annotate both `self` and `other` (and the return of course) with the **same** type variable in each of the signatures. Basically the second solution that @SUTerliakov provided and that we discussed in the comments there.

Answer (score 2):

LSP basically says that given any type `T` and instance `t` of (non-strict) subtype of `T`, you should be able to use `t` whenever something of type `T` is expected (*substitute* the broader type with a narrower one). In your example, with your type definitions you should be able to do `Person() + Person()`, and thus `Dan() + Person()` should also be valid - and your annotation on `Dan` denies that.

Your example could be rewritten with `typing.Self` ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&gist=c42dbed7befe8f0d4da1d7bea0c1a6d9); works only on `mypy` `master`, not yet released on PyPI, and requires python 3.11) :

```
from typing import Self


class Person:
    number: int
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.number = 0

    def __add__(self, other: Self) -> Self:
        self.number = self.number + other.number
        return self


class Dan(Person):
    def __add__(self, other: Self) -> Self:
        self.number = self.number + other.number + 1
        return self
```

If it's too modern, you can mimic the same with regular type variables ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=adfba3fb427946e09315c868d651f784)):

```py
from typing import TypeVar

_PersonSelf = TypeVar('_PersonSelf', bound='Person')
_DanSelf = TypeVar('_DanSelf', bound='Dan')


class Person:
    number: int
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.number = 0

    def __add__(self: _PersonSelf, other: _PersonSelf) -> _PersonSelf:
        self.number = self.number + other.number
        return self


class Dan(Person):
    def __add__(self: _DanSelf, other: _DanSelf) -> _DanSelf:
        self.number = self.number + other.number + 1
        return self
```

Comment: Right, I still haven't gotten used to `Self`... Just a few remarks. 1) The stricter `_DanSelf` is not really necessary. `Dan.__add__` will usually be bound to an instance of `Dan` anyway, thus the type will collapse to `Dan` immediately or to any subclass, if called from one. Even if you use the unbound method and pass `self` "manually", `_PersonSelf` seems totally fine, since the code in the method will remain type safe with _any_ `Person` and the output will be still inferred to be the same type as `self`. There is no harm in the additional type var, but also no real use here.

Comment: 2) Annotating both `self` and `other` with the _same_ type variable imposes a much greater restriction because now both types must be **exactly the same**. I am not saying this is wrong or that you implied anything else. Just thought it was worth mentioning. Again, going from the example code, that seems like an overly strict requirement, when anything that has a numeric `number` attribute will work for `other`. The same goes of course for the `Self` solution.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg you're completely right (and wrote fairly more comprehensive answer!), I used a separate `TypeVar` here to mimic `Self` type closer. Using a `HasNumber` protocol is the best choice here, IMO, because it imposes only necessary restrictions. `_DanSelf` is useful more if `Dan` [defines additional attributes](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=d699852252ebe85ded54f8bf7bdb399e), which are used in context of this typed method, otherwise `_PersonSelf` is sufficient.

Comment: Regarding "exactly the same" - no, I still can add `Dan() + DanSubclass()`, they resolve to least common type `Dan` (like [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=9a55698e5aceb1624b2335cd1685831c))

Comment: You are right. I was very imprecise about the restriction. The problem comes into play when the subtype returned is the broader one, which happens if you just switch places `SubDan() + Dan()`. This will no longer pass because you are not allowed to pass `Dan`, when the `self` type has collapsed to `SubDan`.